# Services to monitor and report if a web site goes down?

Tags: monitoring, service, availability, notification

Are there any services that will monitor a web site and report if it goes down, or experiences unreasonable response time? Which are reputable and recommended?  How does the service notify you when your site is having problems?

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend http://www.pingdom.com.

- You can use pindom to monitor HTTP,
  and various other services, you can
  get it to send you alerts by email,
  text, even DM you on Twitter.
- You can also choose the level of the checks every 10 minutes 5 mintutes etc.
- They will can also give you a report which you can link to on your website, which would give you an uptime report

A more server level service is http://www.serverdensity.com/. Which requires you to add a script to server, but will give you real-time graphs or MySQL, Apache etc. Server Density also allows you to monitor HTTP and TCP for that you won't need to install anything at all and you'll still get graphs and alerts for the monitoring of websites.

Comment: I use Pingdom, and it's great. There's an iPhone app with Push notifications, so you don't need to spend money on SMS

Comment: Server Density does now include website monitoring and can give you alerts based on the site status and response time from different locations around the world.

Answer (score 9):

I use [UptimeRobot](http://www.uptimerobot.com) and have been very pleased. It's pretty basic monitoring (does an URL that you specify respond with 200OK and in a reasonable amount of time?), but it's free, and they offer alerts via email, SMS (via email gateways, which are sometimes delayed), and Twitter.

I recently had an outage while I happened to be using the server, and I was notified within 4-5 minutes. I'm definitely pleased with the service, considering what I'm paying for it. ($0)

Comment: I agree, and offline detection is very precise (checked every 5')

Answer (score 6):

Server-side monitoring software:

- [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) (FOSS)
- [Stashboard](http://www.stashboard.org/) (FOSS)
- [Whiskerboard](https://github.com/bfirsh/whiskerboard) (FOSS)

Site monitoring services:

- [Uptime Robot](http://www.uptimerobot.com/) (free)
- [Service Uptime](http://www.serviceuptime.com/) (free)
- [site 24x7](http://site24x7.com) (free)
- [monitor.us](http://mon.itor.us) (free)
- [Pingdom](http://pingdom.com)
- [Are my sites up?](http://aremysitesup.com/)
- [HostTracker](http://host-tracker.com/)
- [Gomez](http://www.compuware.com/application-performance-management/)
- [servermojo](http://servermojo.com)
- [New Relic](http://newrelic.com)
- [Server Density](http://serverdensity.com)
- [OpManager](http://www.manageengine.com/network-monitoring/service-monitoring.html)

Remote monitoring/testing software:

- [Selenium Remote Control](http://selenium-rc.seleniumhq.org/) (FOSS)
- [mon](http://www.kernel.org/software/mon/man/mon.html) (FOSS)
- [Alchemy Eye](http://www.alchemy-lab.com/products/eye/) (desktop)
- [up.time](http://www.uptimesoftware.com/application-monitoring.php)
- [Easy Network Service Monitor](http://www.javvin.com/easy.html) (desktop)
- [First Alert Service Monitor](http://www.electrasoft.com/fasm.htm) (desktop)

Answer (score 2):

`aremysitesup.com` is an easy solution, with a free option. I use it for my personal blog.

Comment: Now (5 Mar 2014) only 15-day trial is free.

Comment: They must have changed that. They had a fully free option when I posted that.

Answer (score 1):

[Server Mojo](https://www.servermojo.com/cgi-bin/signup.pl) it's not free, but they have a continuous going on offer for 30 bucks / year for monitoring 1 site/domain.

The monitoring is excellent because they don't only check for the server header 200 success, but you can also check for a keyword whitin your page, in this way it tests each time the server uptime and also if the page was really given out completely and if the PHP engine is running.

BTW: i love their leitmotiv: *"RED is BAD!"*

---

**UPDATE March/2012: STAY AWAY from Server Mojo!!!** After trying their service for almonst one year (i paied), I discovered they have no support at all, I received false downtimes signals, and now [looking also at their forum (last updated in April/2011)](http://www.servermojo.com/board/viewforum.php?f=4) I think they are dieing or something anyway is not working out.