# Desktop Software to monitor online status of web site and web-based application

Tags: analytics, monitoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Services to monitor and report if a web site goes down?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/63/services-to-monitor-and-report-if-a-web-site-goes-down)

I'm basically looking for a desktop-based software which can monitor my company's website and the web application's online availability. I know there are few online applications like Uptime Robot which does the same work but I have been asked to find a desktop based software which can monitor running in system tray and notify any down-time. A free software would be great.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Sitemonitor](http://www.sitesmonitor.net/) does this. They offer a free and paid for versions.